# How to swap the folders' name in Git

Tags: git

My project contains several folders similarly as follow:

```
project
|
|- folder1
|- folder2
|- folder3
|- folder4
|- folder5
```

My boss asks me to reorder the sequence. The "folder5" will be put in the 3rd position.

In more detail, the "folder5" will be renamed into "folder3", the "folder3" will be renamed into "folder4", the "folder4" will be renamed into "folder5".

I know, we can rename a folder's name by the command:

```
git mv <old name> <new name>
```

But how can I swap folders' names in Git, so that I don't screw up the anything? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git mv folder5 folder5swp
git mv folder4 folder5
git mv folder3 folder4
git mv folder5swp folder3
```

should do the job

Answer (score 1):

**Rename files and folders with git**

For renaming files or folders use nothing but the git mv command. git mv takes at least two arguments, a source and a destination. If you want to move several files to a single path you may specify n sources but the last argument is the destination.

[CONTINU HERE](http://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/rename-files-and-folders-with-git)

Answer (score 0):

In git you do it with renaming the file.

***`Important`***
You can't just simply rename the file on the file system due to the way that git store information. Git track the content of the file regardless of the filename.

Due to that you have to use the `git mv <file>` and not simply `rm`.
For example look here on the meaning of this. The filename is not part of the content, its a "special" file ingit named `.idx`

[image]